# SharePoint Online suddenly stopped allowing open and edit for HTML files

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, html, html-editor

I have lost the ability to open and edit html files in my document library (specifically site assets), I have CSS and JS files that I can still edit in browser but for HTML files there is no open button and just download.

This was working 2 days ago! I can see the version history and when I last edited the files nothing changed in the library or to the site.

I am using the modern experience

I am using content editors to display this code as an application so I am reluctant to change to the extension to aspx. As a test i saved a file as aspx and when I open it it just opens the content in a blank page with no sharepoint ui to even click open and edit. I just don't understand why this has been working for more than 2 months and then just suddenly stops...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure why it has stopped being the default for HTML files, but if I add `&p=5` to the end of the url I am able to edit online like i can with CSS & JS files